# How to list all child elements for a specific parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just want to list all elements inside a div. If i have:

```
<div class="main_container">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <span>Hi</span>
    <p>World</p>
</div>
```

I will want to have an ouput as a list of

```
h1
span
p
```

To have an idea, I am creating a DOM tree for my simple code snippet in my website. Please Help. Cheers!

Comment: $('.main_container').text();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use the element's `tagName` propery,

```
var tagNames = $('.main_container >').map(function(){
  return $(this).prop('tagName');
}).get();  //['h1','span','p'];
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uFZ68/)

As per your new requirement you can do like,

```
$('.main_container >').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).prop('tagName'));
});
```

And as a side note, i had used this selector `'.main_container >'` for selecting the direct child elements, if you want to select all the descendants then just replace that with `'.main_container *'`

Comment: is there anyway to do this on .each function? i will insert conditions per tag about color coding and indention.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will accept this as the right answer because he is the first to post. I will upvote the answer for everyone who have time for my problem. I tested all upvoted answers and works really fine. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Use like this,

```
$(".main_container").find("*").each(function(){
  alert($(this).prop("tagName"));
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6YAns/6/)**

Answer (score 1):

You have to do like this:

```
$(".main_container").children().each(function(index,item){

alert($(item).prop("tagName"));

 })
```

get children and then iterate on them to get every element.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/C6USL/2/)

You can also create array of it:

```
var elements = $(".main_container").children().map(function(index,item){

    return $(item).prop("tagName");

     })
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/C6USL/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var urarr=[];
$('.main_container >').each(function(){
  urarr.push($(this).prop('tagName'));
});

for(var i in urarr)
$('body').append(urarr[i]+'<br>');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8m4Tj/43/)

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ew3ZU/15/)**  try this

```
 var t = $(".main_container").find("*").map(function(i,val){
    return $(this).prop("tagName");
}).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

For javascript only, you could use `Node.children` or `Node.childNodes'.

**Node.children** skips all white space, ie. #text won't be shown whereas **Node.childNodes** counts in white space.

Note: They both return an array. The text nodes will be shown in the console but will not be visible in the window.

document.getElementsByClassName('main_container')[0].children;    // 0 being index

returns elements.

document.getElementsByClassName('main_container')[0].children;

return #text and elements

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h_awk/jE9K5/)**